# @SuppressWarnings ArrayList<X> may not contain objects of type Y

Tags: java, arraylist, annotations, warnings, contains

I have a class called `CompressedCardInfo` that has an `MtgCard` as a member of it, and `CompressedCardInfo`'s (or classes extending it) have overloaded the equals method to take into account checking if a `CompressedCardInfo` equals an `MtgCard`.

Now this isn't extremely important, as they are only warnings (they bother me however), but when I have `CompressedCardInfo` in an ArrayList and call `ArrayList.contains` or `.indexOf` I get the warning telling me that the list might not have objects of type `MtgCard` in it.

How do I suppress this specific warning about this List? Or is there a better way of handling that kind of comparison?

Thanks.

```
for (Pair<MtgCard, Boolean> card : decklist) {
            /* Translate the set code to TCG name of course it's not saved */
            card.first.setName = CardDbAdapter.getSetNameFromCode(card.first.setCode, database);
            if (changedCardName == null || changedCardName.equals(card.first.mName)) {
                if (mCompressedDecklist.contains(card.first)) {
                    CompressedDecklistInfo existingCard = mCompressedDecklist.get(mCompressedDecklist.indexOf(card.first));
                    if (existingCard.mIsSideboard == card.second) {
                        mCompressedDecklist.get(mCompressedDecklist.indexOf(card.first)).add(card.first);
                    } else {
                        mCompressedDecklist.add(new CompressedDecklistInfo(card.first, card.second));
                    }
                } else {
                    mCompressedDecklist.add(new CompressedDecklistInfo(card.first, card.second));
                }
                if (mShowTotalDecklistPrice) {
                    loadPrice(card.first.mName, card.first.setCode, card.first.mNumber);
                }
            }
        }
```

The calls on lines 5 (contains), 6 (indexOf), and 8 (indexOf). I get warnings there because the ArrayList is of type `CompressedDecklistInfo` (which is extended from `CompressedCardInfo`. This also happens in other places.

Comment: please add some sample code.

Comment: Also, which tool is issuing the warning?

Comment: If `CompressedCardInfo` and `MtgCard` have no base class or interface in common, and you want a `List` to contain both, then it has to be a `List<Object>`. Implementing `equals()` such that `CompressedCardInfo.equals(MtgCard)` can be true is very unusual, and I'd say highly discouraged, especially if `MtgCard.equals(CompressedCardInfo)` is not also true, as it violates the contract of [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-): It must be *symmetric*, i.e. `x.equals(y)` should return true if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns true.

Comment: I believe it is the Java linter in Android Studio/Intellij

Comment: @Andreas it doesn't contain both of those. `CompressedCardInfo` has a member that is of type `MtgCard`, and the `.equals(Object)` method has been overloaded to account for checking if a `CompressedCardInfo` equals an `MtgCard`.  

Basically `CompressedCardInfo` is just another way to represent an `MtgCard`.

Comment: @XVicarious Then do the right thing and iterate the list yourself, comparing `info.mtgCard` to the `MtgCard`. Don't violate contract of `equals()` just so you can use `indexOf`.

Comment: MtgCard can be compared to `CompressedCardInfo` as well. Does this still violate any part of the contract? `MtgCard.equals(CompressedCardInfo)` and `CompressedCardInfo.equals(MtgCard)` both can be true.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm just going to follow best practices and fix these issues properly.